First Answers Queue: 10+ seconds to load each review
In the First Answers review queue, it consistently takes 10+ seconds to load the next review, most of which is waiting on stackoverflow.com to return a response from a POST request to the /review/next-task endpoint. This doesn't happen on any other review queues that I have access to.


As per @cafce25's question in the comments: This is based on an unfiltered queue. If I filter by c#, java, javascript, however, then /review/next-task responds within ≈1.5s, which is totally acceptable. That provides a workaround for me, and possibly a pointer to the development team, but obviously not a solution.

Unfortunately, I don't recall when this first started exactly—though, judging from my review history, it appears to have been a couple of weeks ago.
(Since this started, the number of reviews I complete each day has gone from a consistent forty to a sporadic five or ten.)
The fact that there remain reviewers who do forty reviews a day could suggest that this isn't universal. For me, however, this behavior occurs on every (unfiltered) review, across devices, browsers, and connections, including in Incognito Mode in Chrome.
(I've tested on Safari and Chrome, on iOS and iPadOS, as well as on Windows 10 and 11. It therefore doesn't appear to be related to my browser, connection, or e.g. any caching or plugins.)
Is this a known issue? Is anyone else experiencing this?
I'm obviously happy to submit any of the request or response headers that would be useful here.

From a quick test, I can't reproduce this, but someone else who's not a moderator should probably try it.

I can't reproduce this either, about half a second between tasks. Since you're seenig it across devices, it might be your connection, did you try a different one?

@RyanM: Do you know what per-user considerations factor into this queue that might impact performance for me? It's worth noting I'm the top reviewer in the queue. Obviously, items only require one review to be moved out of the queue, so there shouldn't be any consideration of whether I've already reviewed an item. And as it only applies to a contributor's first answer, it shouldn't be based on e.g. a restriction on the number of reviews from a contributor one reviewer can review. And, regardless, as there are so many new first answers per day, I'd expect the queue to refresh pretty quickly.

@cafce25: That's a good question, and one I should have addressed in my original post. But, yes: This has happened across at least a half-dozen different connections. (Two residences, cellular, various cafes I've worked out of.) I've edited the post to clarify that.

One other thing that comes to mind, do you have any filters on? My quick test was done without any.

@cafce25: Another good question. I totally forgot there were filters in that queue. But, no, I'm not using any filters.

@cafce25: I decided to play around with this. I added [tag:C#], [tag:Java], and [tag:JavaScript], and found that the response time for /review/next-task was reduced from ≈8.5s to ≈1.5s. That's a dramatic improvement, and will at least allow me to continue doing reviews—yay! Though it obviously doesn't solve the original problem, it should be useful if the dev team chooses to take a look at this.

Hmmm, speculation: I wonder if it's somehow specific to people who've done a lot of reviews in a particular queue?  It needs to filter out the reviews you've already done, plus the ones you've skipped, although I think the former doesn't really apply to First Answers... I tried skipping a few dozen reviews in FA to see if it slowed noticeably, and it didn't...and you don't appear to have skipped too many, at least recently.

@RyanM I think it may well be related to the number of reviews - I'm top of the list on several queues and they can be very slow.

@testing-for-ya: Unfortunately, I've exhausted my reviews for the day, so will need to wait until they refresh. That said, I've been testing this every day for two weeks and haven't seen any change, so I'm skeptical. I'll report back.

@greg-449: It's worth noting that I have almost the same number of reviews in Low Quality Answers as I do in First Answers, and yet LQA has been consistently fast.

@testing-for-ya: Totally agreed. I was just responding to Greg's observation that he'd seen slow behavior in multiple queues where he's a top reviewer. I agree that being a top reviewer may be a factor, but it still seems queue dependent.

@testing-for-ya: Confirmed that it still takes more than eight seconds to get a response from the POST request to /review/next-task today without any filters; same result as the last two weeks.

@JeremyCaney Hi there, fixed an index, please try now.

@AaronBertrand: Thank you for your attention! I'll need to wait until tomorrow when I have more reviews available, but I'll report back then.

@AaronBertrand: That seems like it may have done something—but, if it did, it unfortunately went the wrong way: The lag on next-task has gone from a consistent ≈8s to ≈11+s. It remains reasonably fast with filters applied, however. I'll leave a couple of reviews unclaimed today in case you're able to make any further changes, allowing me to test faster next time. Thanks for looking at this.

I'll have to keep investigating tomorrow. I observed the 8 second queries you experienced in our monitoring, and then was able to reproduce. There was an index that wasn't quite right because the query had changed over time. I fixed that, which generated a new plan, and then I was getting sub-second results consistently. I see the long-running executions you're seeing again today, but this time I can't reproduce them (in the database, with your user id, or on the site, obviously with my own). And every single long-running instance is for you and only on that queue, so, it's hard to nail down.

@AaronBertrand: So this is interesting! I just retried it, and it's now quite performant—now just ≈250ms for the POST to /review/next-task! I won't pretend to know why I was initially getting the steep increase, but it now seems as though the changes you implemented have fixed the issue. (I've validated this on two different browsers/OSs/devices.) Thank you!

There was a perfect index for this query when it was first written, but it wasn't updated to account for changes to the query over time. The suitability of the index would only really be a problem for prolific reviewers - there are a handful with over 100K review results, and that's about where the query would fall over.
I made index adjustments over the weekend by adding a better index, which is less disruptive than changing an existing one - especially when other queries can continue using the original index efficiently. One of the execution plans was stubborn, and still picked up the old index, which explains why the OP didn't see any behavior change until I evicted that specific plan from the plan cache. Now it's picking up the new, better index.
I can no longer reproduce the issues for this specific review queue. Note that the index changes are tailored to the queries behind this queue, so there may still be other queues that are affected by similar contributing factors. We'll deal with those case-by-case - hopefully before any user experiences symptoms but, if you observe any sluggishness with a particular queue, please let us know.
